# In kendodropdownlist selected value redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

In kendo dropdown list when select a one dropdown value it should redirect to another page and get those values

I have a kendo dropdown like this

```
$("#txt-ddl").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "name",
        dataValueField: "id",
        dataSource: {                
            transport: {
                read: {                       
                    url: "/XXXX/XXXX",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            }
            }
})
```

i have a kendo dropdown like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve but if you want to do a redirect when item is selected, depending on this particular item you can use `change` or `select` event of kendo DropDownList.

```
$("#txt-ddl").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "id",
    dataSource: {                
        transport: {
            read: {                       
                url: "/XXXX/XXXX",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        }
    },
    change: function(){
        var item = this.dataItem();
        // Make the necessary redirection
        // For example:
        window.location.href = "example.com/" + item.id;
    }
});
```

**Note:** from [kendo docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#events-change) - The event is not fired when the value of the widget is changed programmatically.